# HTTP error 500 when importing additional files for a Python Azure function app

Tags: python, azure, http-status-code-500, azure-function-app

I am currently modifying the code from this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-function-python), and am trying to import an additional file to `__init__` "testsdk.py". Below is my current code within the `__init__` file.

```
import logging
import testsdk 
import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hellod {name}!")
        
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body",
             status_code=400
        )
```

Every time I include `import testsdk`, I get a HTTP error 500 code response.

Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Comment: A silly question, can you see any log on the Function App runtime debugger? One more question, what version of function app are u using and what is the OS used by the service (Linux or Windows based)?

Comment: Hi, @DeividStandard I discovered that the issue lies within testsdk.py as it imports Meraki (from meraki.meraki import Meraki), not importing individual files. Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56564225/http-500-error-when-importing-meraki-sdk-into-python-azure-function-app) as I believe this is the root cause of my error. The OS that I am using for the function app is Linux as it allows me to work with the Python environment and the runtime version is  2.0.12490.0, how would I access the Function App runtime debugger? Thank you for your response!