# HTTP 500 error when importing Meraki SDK into python Azure function app

Tags: python, azure, cisco, azure-function-app

When I import Meraki: `from meraki.meraki import Meraki` it causes a HTTP 500 error. This works as expected on my local machine but when uploaded to my Python Azure Function app it causes the HTTP 500 error. I suspect that this is because the Meraki SDK can be installed on my local machine but not on the Azure function app? How could this be installed within the Azure function app?

Any help with this would be much appreciated!